# Select query for 7 Complete Days ago records using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get the records from 7 **complete** days ago?

using `Interval 7 days` at a time of 1 PM.

For example Select until 7 days ago at 1pm, whereas I need it to be 7 days ago from the start of that day (00:00).

Is there any way within the SQL query to achieve these records or would it require some custom PHP code ?

Comment: you mean all the records between last 7 days till today right?

Comment: @seb has answered it, I just can't accept the answer until another 6 minutes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```